# How to place popup on item click in a recycle card view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

This is my code on  `holder.cart` I am setting `onclick` function to get popup menu but I am getting null pointer exception in lines

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
showPopupMenu(holder.cart);
```

can any one solve this on clicking holder.cart I should display a popupmenu layout but here I had used menuinflater, I want to change it to layout inflater and display the popup view.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class RecyclerAdapterProducts extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterProducts.ViewHolder> {
    //ArrayList<Products> products;
    OnItemClickListener clickListener;
    ArrayList<ImageAndName> imageAndNames;
    private Context mContext;
    //byte[] imz;

    public RecyclerAdapterProducts(ArrayList<ImageAndName> imageAndNames){
        this.imageAndNames=imageAndNames;
        //this.discounts=discounts;
    }

    /*public SimpleRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Products> products){
        this.products=products;
    }*/

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        /*public TextView name,offer;
        public TextView price;*/
        public ImageView im;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView part;
        public ImageButton cart;
        public int position;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.code);
            part = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
            part.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            im = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.productImg);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            cart = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            /*cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
*/
                   /*// LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(RecyclerAdapterProducts.this);
                    View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.quantityalertdialog, null);
                    final EditText subEditText = (EditText)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dialogEditText);

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        *//*builder.setTitle("AlertDialog");
        builder.setMessage("AlertDialog Message");*//*
                    builder.setView(popupView);
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.show();*/

                    //View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.quantityalertdialog, null);
             /*   }
            });*/
            //price = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.serviceDate);

            //offer=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.offer);

        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public RecyclerAdapterProducts(Context mContext, ArrayList<ImageAndName> imageAndNames) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.imageAndNames = imageAndNames;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapterProducts.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_card_individual_product, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerAdapterProducts.ViewHolder holder,int position) {
        holder.im.setImageResource(imageAndNames.get(position).getIconImageResource());
        holder.name.setText(imageAndNames.get(position).getName());
        holder.part.setText(imageAndNames.get(position).getPartno());
        holder.cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.cart);
            }
        });
        holder.position=position;

    }

    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        // inflate menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_album, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        popup.show();
    }

    class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

        public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_add_favourite:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Add to Wishlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_play_next:
                    //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Play next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
        /*final Products pd= products.get(position);
        if (discounts!=null && discounts.size()>0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < discounts.size(); i++) {
                if (pd.getId().equals(((ArrayList)discounts.get(i)).get(0))){
                    ArrayList disc=(ArrayList)discounts.get(i);
                    holder.offer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.offer.setText("Buy "+disc.get(1)+" to get "+disc.get(2)+"% discount");
                }
                else {
                    holder.offer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
        holder.name.setText(pd.getName());
        holder.position=position;
        holder.price.setText(pd.getList_price() + "\u20B9");
        if (pd.getId()!=null) {

            new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ImageModel>() {
                private ViewHolder v;
                private ImageModel img;
                @Override
                protected ImageModel doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                    //v = params[0];
                    final String url = "http://164.164.35.38:443/seis/productTemplateController/getProductImage/"+params[0];
                    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                    img = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ImageModel.class);
                    //byte[] ing=
                    return img;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(final ImageModel result) {
                    //super.onPostExecute(result);.get(0).toString().getBytes()
                    if (result != null && result.getImage()!=null) {
                        //imz=result.get(0).toString().getBytes();
                        // If this item hasn't been recycled already, hide the
                        // progress and set and show the image
                        new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {
                            private ViewHolder v;

                            @Override
                            protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
                                v = params[0];
                                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(android.util.Base64.decode(result.getImage(), 0), 0, android.util.Base64.decode(result.getImage(), 0).length);
                                return bm;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                                super.onPostExecute(result);
                                if (v.position == position) {
                                    // If this item hasn't been recycled already, hide the
                                    // progress and set and show the image
                                    v.im.setImageBitmap(result);
                                }
                            }
                        }.execute(holder);
                        //v.im.setImageBitmap(result);
                    }
                }
            }.execute(pd.getId());
        }*/


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageAndNames.size();
    }
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to display pop-up menu or inflate new layout onclick of cart ??

Comment: I want to inflate layout and set alert dialog showing positive and negative button.

Comment: ok i have posted the answer.. and upvote if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can add those options programmatically without using xml file as below, may be this could help you out.

Here ONE and TWO is showing the index for options which you are giving in popup menu (which is int value actually). Like on 1st position EDIT POST on 2nd position REMOVE POST etc.

1) on holder.cart click open popup menu as below:

```
private final static int ONE = 1;
private final static int TWO = 2;


PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, findViewById(R.id.img_detail_information_options));
popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, ONE, Menu.NONE, getResources().getString(R.string.detail_information_edit_post));
popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, TWO, Menu.NONE, getResources().getString(R.string.detail_information_remove_post));
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
popupMenu.show();
```

Above code will show popup like this:- [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/evejpi)

Comment: I want to keep edit text and two buttons in that popup, is it possible in menu if not can you help in calling layout instead of menu.